# Ruby Meaningful Words -- Remove Stopwords

Tags: ruby, nlp, stop-words

I have an array of speech files, and I need to compare to an array of stopwords to remove the stopwords and leave the remaining meaningful words.

So far I have something like this:

```
stopwords = File.readlines('PATH TO TXT FILE')
speeches = []

Dir.glob('PATH TO ALL SPEECHES').each do |speech|
    #code to read each speech and store into an array
    f = File.readlines(speech)
    speeches << f
end

lincolnSpeech = speeches[0]

def process_file(file_name)
    all_words = file_name.scan(/\w+/)
    meaningful_words = all_words.select { |word| !stopwords.include?(word) }
    return meaningful_words
end
```

I'm embedding the result of this function into my HTML, like so:

```
<ul>
      <li><pre style="white-space: pre-wrap;word-wrap: break-word">#{process_file(lincolnSpeech)}</pre></li>
</ul>
```

But this breaks the page and causes my HTML to disappear entirely. I've narrowed the problem down to the line in the function:

```
meaningful_words = all_words.select { |word| !stopwords.include?(word) }
```

And this line is the culprit. I'm not sure why it breaks my code. Maybe parts of this are deprecated? Can anyone offer some ideas about why this doesn't work, and perhaps alternate ways to achieve the effect I'm going for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually surprised you aren't getting a NoMethod error on the `scan` call. `File.readlines` returns an array of strings, so the `lincolnSpeech` being passed to `process_file` is an array, and I don't think Arrays have a `scan` method.

Assuming your stopwords are one-per-line in that file, I'd do something like this:

```
require 'set'
# Finding an item in a Set will be faster than finding one in
# an array, especially if the array is large.
stopwords = Set.new(File.readlines('PATH TO TXT FILE'))

speech_files = Dir.glob('PATH TO ALL SPEECHES')

lincoln_speech = speech_files[0]

def process_file(file_name)
  speech_words = File.read(file_name).split # get each word in file
  speech_words.reject { |word| stopwords.include?(word) }.join(' ') # reject stopwords and glue it back together
end
```

There are a couple potentially big problems - one is that the argumentless `split` call is a bit naive, and will include punctuation in words it splits, like so.

```
"Well, space is there, and we're going to climb it,".split
# => ["Well,", "space", "is", "there,", "and", "we're", "going", "to", "climb", "it,"]
```

Note the commas attached to the words. Using `split(/\W+/)` is a partial solution but it will then split `"we're"` into `["we", "re"]`.

The other issue is that `join(' ')` assumes every word was separated by a space, when some may have been separated by newlines instead. For simple inputs what I sent along should work reasonably well, but if you're dealing with fairly complex speeches you will probably need to clean up your input a bit in order to accomplish this.

Comment: Did you know that in Ruby, when you have an array of array, eg: `arr = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]`, you can `puts` items of embedded arrays like so (the obvious way): `arr.each { |sub_array| puts sub_array[0], sub_array[1] }`, *but* Ruby is super clever, and allows you doing something like: `arr.each { |left, right| puts left, right }`. To be honest - I didn't run the code from question, but maybe it is possible, when processing `File.readlines` Ruby is clever enough to properly apply `scan `? I just assumed that the all code works properly but the one that @amoeboar narrowed to.

Comment: @PawełDawczak I did know about that, but that doesn't appear to be the case with the provided code. There's a NoMethod error on the array calling `scan` :) https://gist.github.com/alexcavalli/aeb4840a36a1ea289841

Comment: Hey @alexcavalli, this is great you've spent some time to reimplement the solution in your time! Appreciate that you've found different error, thus I'm deleting my answer as it is irrelevant! Cheers!